# Entire function f which satisfy $|f(z)| \leq |\exp(z)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone confirm whether or not my solution to the following question is okay? Or if I'm missing something

**Question:**
Let f be an entire function satisfying: $|f(z)| \leq |\exp(z)| ,\: \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that there exist a $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $|c|\leq 1$ and $f(z) = c \cdot \exp(z), \: \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$.

**Solution:**
Note that $\exp(z) ≠ 0, \: \forall z \in \mathbb{C}$. Hence the function $\dfrac{f(z)}{\exp(z)}$ is an entire function, with $\dfrac{|f(z)|}{|\exp(z)|} \leq 1$. Since it is bounded it must be constant and therefore $f(z) = c \exp(z)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$. It is then seen that $\dfrac{|c \cdot \exp(z)|}{|\exp(z)|} \leq 1 \Leftrightarrow |c| \leq 1$

Thanks

Comment: Looks good!  Well, except that you forgot to put a $1$ at the end.

Comment: Ah yes. But fantastic, thanks!

Comment: (Since no answer is required here, I think it's appropriate to close the question with a pointer to a more general result.)